# Javascript - How to modify complex object based on defined coordinates

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a Javascript object with a shape like this:

```
      obj = {
            'any': [
                'someString',
                {
                    'all': [
                        'another',
                        'andAnother',
                        {
                            'any': [
                                'user',
                                'id',
                                {
                                    'all': [
                                        'yes',
                                        'no'
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                'test'
            ]
        }
```

The object above is just an example.  Basically all objects must have the key of 'all' or 'any' and a value which is an array with only strings or an object.  Each array can only have one object.  The object could be more or less complex but must follow this structure.

I would like to delete elements out of the complex object based on a string (or array or array of arrays -> whatever makes this easiest) formatted like this:

```
"[any][1][all][2][any][2][all][1]"
```

[any][1][all][2][any][2][all][1] defines the location of the string 'no' within the object and should therefore be removed. (`obj[any][1][all][2][any][2][all][1] === 'no'`)

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Is the final item to be removed always inside an array? (if not, it'll make the code a bit more convoluted, due to `splice` vs `delete`)

Comment: Yes - it's always in an array - thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll be easiest by far if the input is an array of keys. Then, you can use `reduce` to iterate over them, accessing the appropriate key of the accumulator each time, passing in the input object for the initial value. Once you get to the next-to-last key, you have the array - use `splice` to remove the item at the desired index:

```js
const obj = {
  'any': [
    'someString',
    {
      'all': [
        'another',
        'andAnother',
        {
          'any': [
            'user',
            'id',
            {
              'all': [
                'yes',
                'no'
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    'test'
  ]
};
const removePath = ['any', 1, 'all', 2, 'any', 2, 'all', 1];

const indexToSplice = removePath.pop();
const arr = removePath.reduce((a, key) => a[key], obj);
arr.splice(indexToSplice, 1);
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

With lodash you can easily do this via [**`_.set`**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#set) & [**_.without**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#without) in one line like this:

```js
obj = { 'any': [ 'someString', { 'all': [ 'another', 'andAnother', { 'any': [ 'user', 'id', { 'all': [ 'yes', 'no' ] } ] } ] }, 'test' ] }

const path = ['any', 1, 'all', 2, 'any', 2, 'all']

const remove = (o, p, v) => _.set(o, p, _.without(_.get(o, p), v))

console.log(remove(obj, path, 'no'))   // Will remove the 'no'
console.log(remove(obj, path, 'yes'))  // Will remove the 'yes'
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```